# How can I restart a Hulu video?

Tags: video, hulu

Sometimes I want to restart a Hulu video from the very beginning (because autoplay started it and I wasn't ready, or some other reason).  Is there a mechanism for this?  I know I can click the time bar.  However, it's hard to get the very beginning, especially on the regular (non-full screen) view.

Answer (score 2):

Hulu added a 10-second rewind feature.  Use the bar to get it within 10 seconds of the beginning, then hit the 10-second rewind (to the right of the play button).

I'm sure this button will be useful at other times, too.